# Not able to catch bash stderr on time

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to extract all pages from a PDF to images using libvps available here: [libvps](https://www.libvips.org/API/current/using-cli.html)
It is working but since the library converts the PDF to images page by page, I want to catch any error that could raise during the conversion.

Here is my bash code that I'm using:

```
num_pgs=10
#num_pgs is the number of pages in the PDF
DESTINATION="/home/user/file.pdf"
imagesStringPath="/home/user/file_"
errorsArray=()
for (( i=0; i<=${num_pgs}; i++ ))
do 
    #2>&1 to catch stderr to stdout
    OUT=$(vips copy ${DESTINATION}[page=$i,dpi=200] $imagesStringPath$i.png 2>&1)
    echo "OUTPUT: "${OUT};
    RETURN="$(isEmpty "${OUT}")"
    if [[ RETURN == *"Output"* ]]; then
        echo ${RETURN};
        errorsArray+=(${OUT})
    fi
done
echo "${#errorsArray[@]}"
```

To test my code, I know that my PDF has 6 pages, so if I put 10 as value for num_pgs=10 I make sure to get errors. My issue is that my code logic seems to catch errors (see output below) but the array I have  `${#errorsArray[@]}` to store them is always 0 and echo `${RETURN};` shows always nothing. I feel like it is running asynchronously even though bash is not async.

Any help please?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Do you really want to split your output string into a separate array element per word? If not, it should be `errorsArray+=( "$OUT" )`. (BTW, all-caps variable names are in a space used for variables meaningful to POSIX-defined tools; the POSIX spec recommends that applications -- like your script -- use names with at least one lowercase character for variables they define themselves).

Comment: Also, `[[ RETURN == *"Output"* ]]` almost certainly is meant to be `[[ $RETURN = *Output* ]]`; note the `$` missing in the original.

Comment: OK yes I will fix it as I'm new to bash but that does not solve the issue right?

Comment: Also, you don't need the `${...}` in your loop -- `for (( i=0; i<=num_pgs; i++ )); do` will suffice. And you're missing some quotes -- run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and address the warnings it raises.

Comment: I can't say what would solve the issue -- there aren't enough details to say why it's happening. Solving as many obvious bugs as we can before trying to narrow things down is a good place to start.

Comment: Paste your script into shellcheck.net to see all the warnings about this code

Comment: (to permit a conclusive answer, we'd want a proper [mre] -- code that can be run without changes to create the same problem and test proposed answers; right now, nobody but you has a `/home/user/file.pdf`, so we can't run your code, so we can't test our answers).

Comment: BTW, one thing you might also find useful is xtrace logging. `bash -x yourscript` or adding `set -x` to the script will make the shell log each step in execution. Knowing what's happening is a good place to start towards being able to ask a narrow, specific question; or to isolating a narrower problem to build a [mre] for it.

Comment: OK I understand Charles Duffy but my code used libvps so how can I send a working code to test?

Comment: What is `isEmpty`? Why not just `if [[ -n $OUT ]]`?

Comment: Use the "Add an Answer" button to add your own answers, instead of editing an answer into the question. (See also [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is edited into the question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) on [meta]). That way you get reputation from any upvotes the answer receives, and it's not privileged over answers anyone else adds (except to the extent that you as the OP can choose a single answer to mark "accepted", which can of course be your own).

Comment: ...re: "my code used libvps so how can I send a working code to test?" -- generally, one can write stub functions to replace tools that only you have, to the extent that the problem can't be reproduced without those tools. For example, you can create a function like `vips() { echo "This is an error message" >&2; return 1; }` to replace a `vips` command which, for the purposes of your test case, needs to fail with an error message written to stderr and a nonzero exit status.

Comment: There's no need to shout.  Don't use all-caps for variable names.  The rule of thumb is to use all-caps for commonly defined names that you expect other tools to recognize (eg USER and PATH and PAGER), and to keep the namespace clear.  It is (unfortunately) common practice to use all caps for variable names, but this practice must cease.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This content was originally edited into the question by the OP.*

---

I followed the corrective tool provided and this is my new code and it works well now. Thanks.

```
#!/bin/bash

DESTINATION="/home/user/my.pdf"
imagesStringPath="/home/user/my"
num_pgs=10

isEmpty(){
    _param="$1"
    if [[ -n "$_param" ]]; then
        echo "Output"
    else
        echo "No Output"
    fi
}

errorsArray=()
imagesStringPath="${DESTINATION%.pdf}"_
for (( i=0; i<=num_pgs; i++ ))
do 
    #2>&1 to catch stderr to stdout
    OUT=$(vips copy ${DESTINATION}[page=$i,dpi=200] "$imagesStringPath$i".png 2>&1)
    echo "${OUT}";
    RETURN="$(isEmpty "$OUT")"
    if [ "$RETURN" = "Output" ]; then
        echo "${RETURN}";
        errorsArray+=("$OUT")
    fi
done
#Check if no errors repotred by vips
echo "${#errorsArray[@]}"
```